# Does the physical interface name in Linux ever change?

Tags: linux, network-interface

When I see the man page for [interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/interfaces.5.html) I see the below. Has anyone seen similar behavior, I had been using Ubuntu for some time and my net-books interface name has not changed for ever.

The  `ifup`  and `ifdown` programs work with so-called "physical" interface names. These  names  are  assigned  to  hardware   by   the   kernel. Unfortunately  it can happen that the kernel assigns different physical interface names to the same hardware at different times;  for  example, what  was  called  "eth0" last time you booted is now called "eth1" and vice versa. This creates a  problem  if  you  want  to  configure  the interfaces  appropriately. A  way to deal with this problem is to use mapping scripts that choose logical interface names  according  to  the properties  of  the  interface  hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Linux distributions will automatically assign permanent names to hardware. Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` mechanism for interface identification and naming is uneeded in this respect.

In the network interface case, identification of previously seen interfaces is based at least on the hardware MAC address. The names are remembered in the form of udev rules; take a look at `/etc/udev/rules.d/*-persistent-*`.

In particular, `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` stores network interface mappings. This file is auto-generated, but can be changed manually, as its header says:

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib64/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.
```

Comment: cool thnx - this file has the mapping between the mac and the interface name. just curious, look like this is a generated file. if i want to change the interface name, how do i do it?

Comment: `# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.
`